# Show header only on first page on Pages

Tags: pages

How to show header only on the first page in a document?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make the front page its own section. From the Document Setup inspector, choose
   Section → Create a new section.
2. With the new section selection, deselect Headers & Footers → Match previous section.

   [image]
3. Customise the header on the first page as you desire.

Answer (score 0):

They moved the Section settings in more recent versions of Pages, at least in version 10.0 (6748).

Now it is located under Format (but only when nothing on the page is selected ;-))

[image]